# How to reorder a column and include all values in that row with the reordering?

Tags: r, geospatial

So I want to create a map showing the covid19 cases per 100.000 in Europe. However, after converting my Large SpatialPolygosDataFrame into a normal data frame with the fortify function and merging my corona information data set with the data frame of polygon data, the plot does not come out correctly anymore. I know that the cause is probably the order column, which is now not ordering the coordinates correctly anymore and has random jumps as you can see in the data frame. This is causing ggplot to incorrectly plot the coordinates in the right sequence. Does anyone know how I can reorder my entire dataframe by the column order. So the "order" column is ascending and all values around it are included in the reorder?

[image: This is an example of my data]
[image: COVID-19 Cases per 100.000]

Comment: Add an `order` column to your dataframe before you merge both dataframes, so after you merge the two, you can reorder your final dataframe according to it.

Comment: @eonurk When I add an ID to the data frame before merging, the ID column also gets scrambled. This is a screenshot from before merging: https://gyazo.com/aea2da74775484446e82c87740d7db22

And this is after: https://gyazo.com/d8b1d74bb65f7ff842a63c3e440bbccd

Comment: yeah then you could just, `df <- df[order(df$order),]`, but you figured it out anyways :)

Comment: @eonurk Yeah, thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with left_join function, this function does not reorder the rows after merging which fixed my problem. Here is a map with the left_join function: [image]